# solr query to return matched text to regex with default schema

Tags: solr, schema

I want to search Solr for server names in a set of Microsoft Word documents, PDF, and image files like jpg, gif.

Server names are given by the regular expression (regex):

```
INFP[a-zA-z0-9]{3,9}
TRKP[a-zA-z0-9]{3,9}
PLCP[a-zA-z0-9]{3,9}
SQRP[a-zA-z0-9]{3,9}
....
```

**Problem**

I want to get the text in the documents matching the regex. eg. `INFPWSV01`, `PLCPLDB01`.

I've indexed the files using Solr/Tikka/Tesseract using the default schema.

I've used the highlight search tool

```
hl ticked
hl.usePhraseHighlighter ticked
```

Solr only returns the metadata (presumably) like filename for the file containing the pattern(s).

**Questions**

1. Would I have to have modify the managed schema?
2. If so would I have to save the file content in the schema?
3. If so is this the way to do it:
   a. solrconfig.xml <- inside my "core"
   [image]
   b. Remove line
   [image]
   as I want meta data
   c. Change this in the managed schema
   [image]

   `stored=false to stored=true`
   [image]

Comment: Please don't add text as images - it makes the text in the question non-searchable and hard to parse for those that have reduced eyesight. Have you tried using `hl.regex.pattern` for the highlighter? You might be able to tweak that to return what you want `with `hl.fragmenter` set to regex.

Comment: Sorry had a real problem inserting the html code